# Aurelia bindable properties

Tags: typescript, aurelia

Is there a way to control the order of execution for "bindableChanged" methods in the same class?

```
export default class{
   @bindable selectedType: any;
   @bindable entity: any;

    async selectedTypeChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
     if (newValue != oldValue && oldValue != undefined)
        if (newValue.id == "model" || newValue.id == "secondModel") {
            this.isModel= true;
        }
        else {
            this.isModel= false;
        }
    }    
    async entityChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
     if (newValue != oldValue) {
            var selectedModel = newValue[0].model;

            this.selectedType = selectedModel;
            this.value = this.getDataById(
            newValue[0].model, 
            newValue[0].id);
        }
}
```

Another solution that will work in my case, is to be able to control the selectedTypeChanged(newValue, oldValue){} events... like newValue = undefined, newValue = "choose...";

SelectedType is a bindable property for a Select html, and I have scenarios when I need to select the default value programmatically.